# NSReadPixel gives wrong colour on setting layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created one sample application with base sdk 10.9 and deployment target as 10.9.
I have the code which gives NSColor object on mouseUp event

```
// source view mouse up event

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    [self lockFocus];
    NSColor* color = NSReadPixel(point);
    [self unlockFocus];
     Delegate* delegate = (Delegate*)[NSApp delegate];
    [delegate.colorView setColor:color]; // destination view object
    [delegate.colorView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

After mouse clicked, I have set color object to destination view, and call setNeedsDisplay to render the new colour on its bounds.

```
//destination view drawRect method

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    // Drawing code here.
    if (_color) {
        [_color set];
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    }
}
```

It works fine, and set the colour of the clicked position on the destination view.

Now when I set the wants layer as

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

the below code for getting colour is not working. It gives some unrelated colour w.r.t the clicked location on view

```
NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
[self lockFocus];
NSColor* color = NSReadPixel(point);
[self unlockFocus];
```

How to tackle this issue. Again, when I set to 10.7 sdk as base sdk and deployment target as 10.7 this issue does not come up. Let me know how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are converting the point to the coordinate system of the view you are targeting.

The docs say this on NSReadPixel :

Because the passedPoint parameter is relative to the current coordinate system, if you wish to read a pixel from a specific view, you must convert points in the view’s coordinate system to the current coordinate system before calling this function. Alternatively, you can lock focus on the view and then specify the pixel coordinate in the view’s coordinate system.
When mapping the specified point to pixel boundaries, this method rounds to the nearest pixel. For more information on how coordinate points map to the underlying pixels, see “Coordinate Systems and Transforms” in Cocoa Drawing Guide.

Comment: converting to view coordinate is done in below code:NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

Comment: Passing nil gives you the same thing back, the point in the window coordinates. You need to supply the view whose pixel you want. At least that's how the docs read.